# image floating text and clear everything?

Tags: css, image, css-float

always the same structure.

image (with float:left) text
image (with float:left) text
image (with float:left) text
image (with float:left) text

however if the text is not long enough the next image gets floated again and again.
i always want one image with a bit of text floated beside to it. then there should be a break and the same again. However i have no real break, due to the cms. i want to style it this way with css.

i tried to set a clear:both to every image but that doesn't work.

any idea how i can achieve that.
currently every img has:

```
img {
float:left;
clear:both; /*doesn't do anything*/
}
```

Comment: can you please post an example of your html. I assume you have multiple img tags within a single <p /> which is why this method is not working. With some markup it is more likely that someone will have a bright idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `clear:left` on the image:

```
<style>
    img {
        float:left;
        clear:left;
    }

    p {
        float:left;
    }
</style>

<img src="http://dummyimage.com/300" alt=""><p>text</p>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/300" alt=""><p>text</p>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/300" alt=""><p>text</p>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/300" alt=""><p>text</p>
```

This will prevent the images from having anything on the left-hand side, forcing them onto a new line.

Answer (score -1):

`clear` has to appear in the first element that should not float anymore. Therefore, using both `float` and `clear` on one element eliminates itself.

Comment: no... not really. Clear forces an element to effectively ignore floated elements to the left or right (or both) of it. http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_clear.asp